# Check if user in a database is banned JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Using an oracle database, I need to perform a check to see if a user in my 'users' table is banned or not. The user is banned if his column 'banned' has a value of '1', '0' if he is not.

I have the following working code here:

```
public boolean banUser(String username)
    {//TODO check if user is banned already
        try 
        {
            pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET banned = 1 WHERE username = ?");
            pstmnt.setString(1, username);
            pstmnt.execute();
            logger.info("Banned User : " + username);
            return true;
        } catch ( SQLException e ) { e.getMessage(); }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm not sure how to perform an if statement on top of a prepared statement. Any ideas?

Comment: This code isn't checking if a user is banned, this code is creating the ban.  For checking, you have several options depending on your design.  You can add something like `WHERE banned = 0` to a `SELECT` statement to filter out banned users, you can return banned users and check for the value in code, etc.

Comment: Why can't you fire a select query `select banned WHERE username = ?` and see if you get a result ?

Comment: Your working code updates a user row to ban him or her.  You need to do a select and test the banned column to do a check or test.

Comment: Voted to close as "not a real question".  The Question title/text and the code are contradictory, and the OP has not corrected it or answered any of the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your update statement from:

```
conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET banned = 1 WHERE username = ?");
```

to:

```
conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET banned = 1 WHERE username = ? and banned = 0");
```

And execute it using `executeUpdate()` instead of `execute()`. The difference is that `executeUpdate` returns the number of rows affected by the update, so you will not need to execute a SQL statement to retrieve if the user was already banned.

```
//...
pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET banned = 1 WHERE username = ? and banned = 0");
pstmnt.setString(1, username);
int affectedRows = pstmnt.executeUpdate();
boolean wasUserBanned = affectedRows > 0;
//...
```

Comment: _I need to perform a check to see if a user in my 'users' table is banned or not_ The OP wants another method to check if a given user is banned, he doesn't want to check how many users are banned when performing the update

Comment: Sometimes you need to understand what's his *real intent* and provide better solutions to it, right?

Comment: Won't this end up banning any user that currently isn't banned?

Comment: @MarlonBernardes Yes, but i'm pretty sure this is not the real intent, he has a user, he wants to check if it's banned, an update is not needed

Comment: @DaveHowes it will ban the user `username` given it isn't currently banned.

Comment: I'm with BackSlash - I don't think this is his intention. I think the question is confusing as the UPDATE code has been posted, but I think he's just wanting to check username to see if they have been banned before allowing them access to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query, and store results in a `ResultSet`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND banned = 1
```

This will return all banned users with a specific username.

```
pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND banned = 1");
pstmnt.setString(1, username);
ResultSet rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()) {
    //The user is banned
} else {
    //The user is not banned
}
```

If you want a method version:

```
public boolean isUserBanned(String user) throws SQLException {
    pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND banned = 1");
    pstmnt.setString(1, username);
    ResultSet rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();
    return rs.next();
}
```

Comment: If the `user` column has a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, then `SELECT COUNT(*)` would be better than `SELECT *`.  And, `ResultSet.getBoolean(int)` converts 0 and 1 to `false` and `true`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBoolean(int).  Perhaps the poster should create a `BANNED_USERS VIEW`?

Comment: You can remove the `if`s, just having `rs.next(); return rs.getBoolean(1);` at the end.

Comment: @EricJablow No. My query returns nothing if the user is not banned, so `rs.getBoolean(1)` would generate an exception in that case.

Comment: With the `COUNT(*)`, it would return exactly one row in any case.

Answer (score 1):

This is my variation on @BackSlash's version, assuming `username` has a UNIQUE constraint:

```
pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ? AND banned = 1");
pstmnt.setString(1, username);
ResultSet rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();  // Always returns exactly one row.
rs.next();
return rs.getBoolean(1);               // Converts 0, 1 to false, true.
```

You can let the database do more of the work with

```
CREATE VIEW BANNED_USERS AS
    SELECT username FROM USERS
    WHERE banned = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a select after the update:

```
    pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT banned FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    Resultset rs = pstmnt.execute();
    pstmnt.setString(1, username);
    int isBanned = 0;
    while(rs.next()) {
        isBanned = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    if(isBanned == 1) {
        System.out.println("User is banned")
    }
```

Comment: `boolean isBanned = rs.getInt();` no way to compile that. Should be `isBanned = rs.getInt(1);`

Answer (score -1):

Reusing your code: (Assuming the user already exists)

```
public boolean isUserBanned(String username)
    {//TODO check if user is banned already
        try 
        {
            pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("select username WHERE username = ? and banned = 1");
            pstmnt.setString(1, username);
            Resultset rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();
            //logger.info("Banned User : " + username);
            return rs.next();
        } catch ( SQLException e ) { e.getMessage(); }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This checks if the user exists, not if he is "banned"

Comment: You'd need to return `rs.next().getBoolean(1)`.  Also, use try-with-resources, and do something with the `SQLException` if one occurs.

Comment: @GyroGearless, thanks for pointing it out. It was a mad rush to be the first to answer :(. I have corrected the query assuming that there is already a username.